# How to pass a string value from a class to another in the same activity in Flutter?

Tags: string, class, flutter, pass-data

// I cant find a way to pass a string from a class to another. They are both in the same screen and i want to pass the index from a pageview on class to another. Any help would be grateful!

```
//on the first class//


            onPageChanged: (int index) {
            _sendDataToAnotherClass(context, index);
            _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
          }),
      ),
    );
}


  void _sendDataToAnotherClass(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final String texttosend = index.toString();
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return new personaname(text: texttosend);
            }

        ));
  }


//on the second class//

 final String text ;
 personaname({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Some code of what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: please edit your question and use the code format tool. Reading code as a single string like the comment section does is a bit of a task

Comment: You said that these are on the same screen but I see a navigator.push() call which means it can't be on the same screen.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: They are on the same screen but in different dart files. The navigator.push() is the only solution i have found and its not working.

Comment: I just want to pass the index from a dart file to another.

Comment: @GeorgeKordatos how do you import the other file is it by the File Path in lib folder

Comment: @GeorgeKordatos how do you import ?

Comment: @MohamedElrashid what do you mean?

Comment: @GeorgeKordatos do you use import 'file.dart';

Comment: The way a file is imported is not a concern here.

Comment: @AdrianMurray thanks, if he use difrent file your code will not work with file name import , it's a dart lang thing try it you self use 2 files

Comment: I ran into this problem back in beta but it hasn't made a difference since 1.0.

Comment: @AdrianMurray maby he is running and old sdk

Answer (score 0):

if your personaname is a class (just fyi if that is indeed a class the proper format is to capitalize the first letters of each word - PersonaName), and that class is a stateful widget you could pass the data down to it and do a call within the state to override the [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) method to setState on data changes. This would mean you don't need the value notifier.

Something like this might do what you're looking for:

```
class PageViewHolder extends StatelessWidget{

  PersonaName name = PersonaName(text: 'text',);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return PageView(
      onPageChanged: (p){
        var textToSend = 'do logic to decide name';
        name.text = textToSend;
      },
    );
  }

}


class PersonaName extends StatefulWidget{
  String text;

  PersonaName({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>_PersonaName();
}

class _PersonaName extends State<PersonaName>{



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.text);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(PersonaName oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if(widget.text != oldWidget.text){
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great this should work. The only problem is that the String text in the PersonaName class is null.

Comment: I only provided the bare minimum to pass the data. How you construct your classes is up to you. If this solves the passing of data question please mark it as solved.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented the suggestions so I can't tell you what's going wrong.